# How to use $nin to exclude array of objects in Meteor, MongoDB, React

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I want to exclude array of objects from my query when fetching Object.

```
mixins: [ReactMeteorData],
getMeteorData() {

  // Standard stuff
  var selector = {};
  var handle = Meteor.subscribe('videos', selector);
  var data = {};

  // Return data = OK!
  data.video = Videos.findOne({ _id: this.props._id });

  // Fetch objects with $lte _id to exclude, Return id_ field array = OK!
  data.excnext = Videos.find({ votes: data.video.votes, _id: {$lt: data.video._id}},{fields: {_id:1}},{sort: {_id: 1},limit:50}).fetch();

  // Fetch objects by Votes, Exclude array of objects with $nin = NOT OK!
  data.next = Videos.findOne({ _id: { $ne: this.props._id,  $nin:data.excnext }, votes: { $gte: data.video.votes}},{ sort: { votes: 1, _id: 1 }});
  return data;
},
```

**Why is $nin not working like expected?**
Am unsure if am doing something wrong when fetching my array or when returning it using $ini

**Logged example = data.excnext**

```
[ { _id: 'A57WgS6n3Luu23A4N' },
  { _id: 'JDarJMxPAnmeTwgK4' },
  { _id: 'DqaeqTfi8RyvPPTiD' },
  { _id: 'BN5qShBJzd6N7cRzh' },
  { _id: 'BSw2FAthNLjav5T4w' },
  { _id: 'Mic849spXA25EAWiP' } ]
```

Grinding on my first app using this stack. My core setup is  Meteor,Flow-router-ssr, React-layout, MongoDB, React. What am trying to do is to fetch next object by votes, problem is that sometimes several objects have the same amount of votes, so then i need to sort it by id and exclude unwanted objects.

- First of all am seeking the answer how to use $nin correct in my example above
- Second, Suggestions / examples how to do this better are welcome, There could be a much better and simpler way to do this, Information is not easy to find and without any previous experience there is a chance that am complicating this more than needed.

// ❤ peace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case `$nin` needs an array of id strings, not an array of objects which have an `_id` field. Give this a try:

```
data.excnext = _.pluck(Videos.find(...).fetch(), '_id');
```

That uses [pluck](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck) to extract an array of ids which you can then use in your subsequent call to `findOne`.